# UITableView Delete mode Issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have an app built with iOS 6 SDK and that uses a TableView. The tableview is enabled with edit mode to delete the rows. When the user clicks on the Edit button it shows the Hyphen on the left side and Delete button for each row. Either, When the user clicks the hyphen button to disable delete mode or tap on done button to disable delete mode, edit mode stops working once for all. This issue happens only in iOS8 and not on previous versions. Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue before.

Comment: Since there was not fix from Apple, I have upgraded my app to iOS 8 SDK

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well.. Seems like a bug from Apple. I've found a way to kind of go around it though.. It isn't perfect but it works a little bit:)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     tableView.editing = YES;
     [tableView reloadData];
     [tableView setNeedsLayout];
     [tableView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This reloads the data and resets the editing mode. You need to tap the minus button 2 times instead of once but i'm working on a way around this.